# What is the best way to share the blockchain and get it verified by the wallet?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I am the owner of [BlockchainDownload](http://en.blockchaindownload.nl) and am looking for a way to get some trust in the website.

I have shared the link in a couple of topics an get the response "Please do not suggest that people download a preindexed blockchain from you. Doing so implies they need to trust you to tell them exactly how much money everyone owns.".

I do now generate a .rar with the whole data directory exept of the peers.dat and wallet.dat.

Is there a way to share the blockchain on a more trustworthy way?

Comment: There might be eventually, when we get "UTXO commitments".

Comment: but is it better to only share the blocks themselves? makes that the proces more trustworthy?

Comment: @rollo1996 Yes, just sharing the blocks is safe. They'll be processed at startup just as if they were received from network. It's also not about being trustworthy or not, but about trust not mattering. By just downloading blocks, people do not *have* to trust you, as there is nothing you could do to defraud them.

Comment: to share the blocks, the data/blocks/index directory is also not included right?

Comment: do I also need to include the rev*.dat files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can literally concatenate all the *.dat files and share that. The user downloading can use that as their base download by using the bootstrapping option (-loadblock) in bitcoin core.

Generally, the trust a user puts in the blocks you give them is not really needed since the proof-of-work is verifiable by the new node. New blocks will also reference the previous block so it's easy enough to verify that they're on the chain that new blocks are coming in from.